# SSRS rows page breaking on export

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, reporting-services

I have a row group in my SSRS report that limits the table when it is used in a webspart in sharepoint.

```
=Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/8)
```

this works fine, i get 8 rows per page. but the issue is when i try and export the table.
For example when i export to PDF i get 8 items then a lot of white space and on the next page i get 8 more items, when what i really want is my exports not to have paging until it is out of room on the page. 
seems like my expression broke my exporting. is there a correct way to have both?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i was able to get it to work from the  example in this post

http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/115/posts/11163/disable-page-break-when-exporting-to-excel-in-ssrs-2008-r2.aspx

since i am doing data processing RenderFormat can't be used in a lot of places but this way worked really well

Answer (score 0):

I found [this: Conditional report rendering based on render formats for SSRS Reports](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2106/conditional-report-rendering-based-on-render-formats-for-ssrs-reports/), you should change your expression to test the [RenderFormat](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/05/02/globals-renderformat-aka-renderer-dependent-report-layout.aspx). Or perhaps you can use RenderFormat.Name (e.g. EXCEL, PDF etc) to be very specific.

```
=IIF(
  Globals.RenderFormat.IsInteractive, 
  Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/8),
   ... in case of other formats....
)
```

[image]

Comment: hi Preet, thanks for the articles and example, but unfortunately because i am doing data processing (since its in a grouping) i can't use Globals!RenderFormat, i noticed you example you used Globals.RenderFormat.IsInteractive but that didn't work either. i kept getting an error that my definition is in valid when i would delpoy. this is what i did (at least one of the trys, =IIf(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive, Ceiling(RowNumber(Nothing)/8), nothing)

Comment: IF I recall correctly, RenderFormat was added in SSRS 2008R2. What version of SSRS are you using?

Comment: i'm using SSRS 2008R2. when i go into the expression i see RenderFormat under "Built-in Fields"

Comment: Can you preview it before deployment? What Error message do you get when you preview it?

Comment: when i preview i get an error that says "The GroupExpression expression for the tablix 'table1' refers to the global variable RenderFormat, which is not valid for this type of report item expression"

Comment: Just a thought how about setting a hidden report parameter to Globals!RenderFormat.XXX and then using Parameters!MyHiddenParm.Value instead?

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestion, i just tried that and i get an error because MyHiddenParam is referring to a RenderFormat lol

Comment: What about a report variable instead? Set it's default to the RenderFormat.IsInteractive. Or perhaps a calculated Field on the dataset using the parameter or variable?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [Handling Export format](http://www.bi-rootdata.com/2012/10/efficient-way-of-handling-excel.html)

Comment: unfortunately i can't use RenderFormat when it's apart of a group, which mine is (otherwise i could have just used that and easily be done).